# How to read Superspeed or Highspeed of a USB flash drive in C#

Tags: c#, usb, enumeration

I have found this question and answer within this site here:[Detect if device is using USB 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820091/detect-if-device-is-using-usb-3-0?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
but when I ran the program, the result never returned a SuperSpeed connection. I plugged in the USB3.0 flash drive into the USB 3 port so it's supposed to return SuperSpeed to me.

The complete code is the following piece from <@Sani Huttunen>

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

class MainCode
{
private static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var hostCtrls = USB.GetHostControllers();

    foreach (var hostCtrl in hostCtrls)
    {
        var hub = hostCtrl.GetRootHub();
        foreach (var port in hub.GetPorts())
        {
            if (port.IsDeviceConnected && !port.IsHub)
            {
                var device = port.GetDevice();
                Console.WriteLine("Serial: " + device.DeviceSerialNumber);
                Console.WriteLine("Speed:  " + port.Speed);
                Console.WriteLine("Port:   " + device.PortNumber + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and the library from here:
http://read.pudn.com/downloads105/sourcecode/windows/vxd/432626/USBLib/USB.cs__.htm

In the library, I see that they only have:

```
enum USB_DEVICE_SPEED : byte
    {
        UsbLowSpeed,
        UsbFullSpeed,
        UsbHighSpeed,

    }
```

The question here is how to read the correct speed of the USB flash drive. With the above code and the library, my USB 3.0 flash drive in the USB 3 port always returns Highspeed instead of Superspeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to backward compatibility, SuperSpeed/USB3 devices are reported back as HighSpeed/USB2, if you really need to know if the device is Super speed, you need to use:

IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450861(v=vs.85).aspx

I hope this helps