# How can I detect if a device in is in a USB2 vs USB3 port in a c# application?

Tags: c#, usb

As above, I've looked around and seen various ways of getting some bits of information about USB ports/devices but nothing that quite does what I'm after.

The software uses a device that needs to be plugged into a USB3 port for performance reasons, and so I'm wanting to add a warning/notification when it's been put into a USB2 port on software startup basically. I'm not needing to detect when a usb has been inserted as it should have been done in advance, just to detect the type of port it's in.

I came across this which looked promising but it doesn't seem to work, failing to populate the list of devices, returning false on the call to SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail resulting in empty items in the list it returns.
[Detect if device is using USB 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820091/detect-if-device-is-using-usb-3-0)

Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated!