# How can one programmatically determine the speed of a USB controller?

Tags: c#, usb

I have found references to how determine the speed of a USB port ([such as in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324587/how-can-i-determine-the-speed-of-a-usb-port)) but how do you figure the same thing out for a controller?

Comment: Just curious, why you wish to determine the speed of USB?? port